# Automake: Why is my Makefile picking files from the source directory instead of the build directory?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, autotools, automake

I'm using [Automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/).

I have a few source files listed in `dist_man1_MANS` like this:

```
dist_man1_MANS = some-file.1 some-other-file.1
```

Now, Automake + `configure` eventually generate this in `Makefile`:

```
dist_man1_MANS = some-file.1 some-other-file.1

# ...

install-man1: $(dist_man1_MANS)
    # generated recipe here
```

Since I'm not prefixing the `.1` files with `$(srcdir)`, I assume that, since I run `make` from the build directory (its current working directory), it should find them in the build directory.

So, I'm doing an out-of-tree build, for example, in `/tmp/build`:

```
/path/to/src/configure --prefix=$(pwd)/install
make
make install
```

and the build succeeds, that is, `make` finds the man pages and installs them. They are not in the build directory, however. I add this to the generated Makefile:

```
install-man1: $(dist_man1_MANS)
    @echo ">>> $(^)"
    @echo "::: $(dist_man1_MANS)"
    # generated recipe here
```

Now, I would assume that both `echo`s print the same thing, because `$^` means [*the names of all the prerequisites, with spaces between them*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html). To my surprise, the output is:

```
>>> /path/to/src/some-file.1 /path/to/src/some-other-file.1
::: some-file.1 some-other-file.1
```

So:

1. How did `make` find the `/path/to/src/` prefix exactly? Where does it come from in this very context?
2. Why do `$^` and `$(dist_man1_MANS)` differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Automake sets the [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) variable in its generated `Makefile`, a special variable for `make`, to something like:

```
VPATH = /path/to/src
```

From the previous links:

> **4.5.1 `VPATH`: Search Path for All Prerequisites**
>
> The value of the `make` variable `VPATH` specifies a list of directories that make should search. Most often, the directories are expected to contain prerequisite files that are not in the current directory; however, `make` uses `VPATH` as a search list for both prerequisites and targets of rules.

So `make` searches for the `some-file.1` and `some-other-file.1` prerequisites in the current working directory first, then for `/path/to/src/some-file.1` and `/path/to/src/some-other-file.1` if it cannot find the first ones. In this case I understand why `$^` is different from `$(dist_man1_MANS)`: `$^` is the list of *effective* (resolved) prerequisites.